# How to redirect post

Tags: php, css

I pull a post from a website then i display it on my website. I want when a user clicks on it i want her to be redirected to the source url but when i share it i want the url to have my url like www.mywebsite.com/post url. Am trying this code below

```
<div class="post-item mb-3 shadow-sm bg-white">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap p-1">
        <div class="post-feat-image pr-2 d-flex align-items-center"><a href="<?= e_attr(post_url($t['loop'])); ?>" class="post-img-link" <?= post_attrs($t['loop']); ?>>
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAACCAYAAABytg0kAAAAFElEQVQYV2N8+vTpfwYGBgZGGAMAUNMHXwvOkQUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" data-src="<?= e_attr(feat_img_url($t['loop.post_featured_image'])); ?>" alt="<?= e_attr($t['loop.post_title']); ?>" class="post-feat-img img-zoom"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="post-info px-2 py-1"><a href="<?= e_attr(post_url($t['loop'])); ?>" <?= post_attrs($t['loop']); ?>>
            <h3 class="post-title" title="<?= e_attr($t['loop.post_title']); ?>">
                <?= e(limit_string($t['loop.post_title'], 70), false); ?>
            </h3></a>
            <div class="post-feed-logo mb-1">
                <img src="<?= feed_logo_url($t['loop.feed_logo_url']); ?>" class="feed-logo-img">
            </div>
            <div class="post-time text-muted py-1">
                <?= svg_icon('time', 'text-success'); ?>
                <?= time_ago($t['loop.post_pubdate'], _T); ?> 
                <?= svg_icon('eye-outline', 'text-primary'); ?>
                <?= localize_numbers($t['loop.post_hits'], _T); ?>
                <a href="https://facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?= e_attr(post_url($t['loop'])); ?>" class="btn btn-facebook rounded-0 btn-share" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?= e_attr(__('Share on Facebook', _T)); ?>" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
                <?= svg_icon('facebook'); ?>
                </a>
                <a href="http://twitter.com/share?text=<?= e_attr($t['post.post_title']); ?>&url=<?= e_attr(post_url($t['loop'])); ?>" class="btn btn-twitter rounded-0 btn-share" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?= e_attr(__('Share on Twitter', _T)); ?>" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
                <?= svg_icon('twitter'); ?>
               </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just enclose the whole code in `<a></a>` tag and in CSS just remove all the text decoration.